# How to install Octave without GUI in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, octave

I am really angry. Just installed the new ubuntu and run `apt-get install octave`. I got tons of crap installed (like Java, some QT libraries, and other pollution).

How can I install Octave in Ubuntu 16.04 without the dependency to any GUI stuff? If the latest version of Octave does not have a "clean" package, then how to install an old version which does not have the GUI?

Comment: You are still able to run Octave in command line if you do such an installation. And such stuff like Java, Qt etc may be needed when installing other software, so just keep it

Comment: submit a bug report asking for an `octave-cli` package without Qt/Java/etc.

Answer (score 10):

Don't be angry :)

I installed `GNU Octave, version 4.0.0` on my fresh Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Here's how you can install it in your system:

1. Using [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~octave/+archive/ubuntu/stable)

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:octave/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install octave`

2. Compiling the source yourself

`sudo apt-get build-dep octave
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-4.0.0.tar.gz
tar xf octave-4.0.0.tar.gz
cd octave-4.0.0/
./configure
make 
sudo make install`

Run `octave-cli` on your terminal to verify.

---

Choose what option fits you. I used PPA, coz it's simple.

Comment: Does that adress the “without GUI” part in any way?

Comment: Why do you need to use PPA? Isnt the conventional method just to use `sudo apt-get install octave`?

Answer (score 5):

You can install Octave from source without any GUI stuff.

```
$ wget -c ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/octave-4.2.1.tar.xz
$ tar -xf octave-4.2.1.tar.gz
```

(or newer version, depending on what you want)

```
$ cd octave-4.2.1/
$ ./configure --without-java
```

The configure script will likely give you a bunch of errors and/or warnings because of missing dependencies. In fact Octave is quite forgiving with missing libraries, but a few are obviously required or at least highly advisable to have. I would at least

```
$ sudo apt-get install gfortran libfftw3-dev libfltk1.3-dev libarpack2-dev libqrupdate-dev libreadline-dev texinfo
```

Then again `./configure --without-java`. It may still give errors, depending on what you have already installed on your system. The standard rule is: for e.g.

```
configure: WARNING: FFTW3 library not found.
```

fetch the library with `sudo apt-get install libfftw3-dev`.

Once the configure script runs with no warnings except those relating to GUI, Java, audio, or logos, you can start the build:

```
$ make
```

This will take some time. If you're in a hurry and/or have some CPU cores to spend, use `make -j4` for quadruply-parallel compilation.

Once this is done, check that everything works with e.g.

```
$ ./run-octave
GNU Octave, version 4.0.0
Copyright (C) 2015 John W. Eaton and others.
This is free software; see the source code for copying conditions.
There is ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  For details, type 'warranty'.

Octave was configured for "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu".

Additional information about Octave is available at http://www.octave.org.

Please contribute if you find this software useful.
For more information, visit http://www.octave.org/get-involved.html

Read http://www.octave.org/bugs.html to learn how to submit bug reports.
For information about changes from previous versions, type 'news'.

octave:1> [1 2 3; 4 5 6]
ans =

   1   2   3
   4   5   6

octave:2> [1 2 3; 4 5 6] \ [1; 0]
ans =

  -0.94444
  -0.11111
   0.72222

octave:3> svd([1 2 3; 4 5 6])
ans =

   9.50803
   0.77287
```

If something doesn't work yet, you may wish to install more libraries, then configure and `$ make` again. (Perhaps you first need to `$ make clean` so it actually builds anew, not sure about this.)

If it works to your satisfaction, finally bake the install to your system:

```
$ sudo make install
```

Answer (score 4):

start without gui

```
octave --no-gui
```

For more options check out

```
octave --help
```

Answer (score 2):

A workaround for this problem was to install [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html#linux-installers) (no sudo needed) via

```
$ wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
$ bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

and then install [octave package](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/octave) in a new conda environment via

```
$ conda create --name myoctave --channel conda-forge octave
$ source activate myoctave # or conda activate myoctave
(myoctave) $ octave-cli
```

afterwards you can delete the conda environment which will delete all octave packages without any trace for your linux system

```
(myoctave) $ source deactivate # conda deactivate
$ conda env remove --name myoctave
```

Comment: Did not know that conda could install Octave! This is great.