# Error running Octave in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: octave

I just followed the answer in:
[How to install Octave without GUI in Ubuntu 16.04?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280195/how-to-install-octave-without-gui-in-ubuntu-16-04#new-answer?newreg=a3e30a76cc184b50ae80b8c39bf2463d)
to install octave in ubuntu 16.04 and apparently it worked fine.

Running octave-cli in terminal apparently works

But when I went to run octave clicking on its icon I got the following error:

> The settings file
>   /home/user/.config/octave/qt-settings
>   does not exist and can not be created.
>
> Make sure you have read and write permissions to
>   /home/user/.config/octave
>
> Octave GUI must be closed now.

Can anyone please help me fix this, so I can run octave?

Comment: There are 2 answers in the question you linked, and note that the answer with more upvotes offers 2 methods. Which answer _and_ method did you actually follow?

Comment: Which ever you think is the best one. I'd probably go for the one with more upvotes, because if one of the methods doesn't work I can always try the other one.

Answer (score 32):

```
cd .config/octave

sudo chown $USER qt-settings
```

Comment: in directory `~/snap/octave/306/.config/octave`: `qt-settings: no such file or directory`

Answer (score 3):

You can use "sudo octave" from the terminal in order to give access to octave.
The con is that you have to open octave every time by this way.

Comment: Using `sudo` at random like this is not really a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

What helped me on ubuntu 14.04 is the following

```
cd .config/octave/

sudo chmod u+w qt-settings
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion, but nothing happens after that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
This worked for me:

```
cd ~/.config/octave 
sudo chown user:user qt-settings
sudo chmod u+w qt-settings
```

In place of the word "user" you must place your username.

Answer (score 0):

Got this problem on 17.04. The problem is the permissions of the folder, not the file.

I did this:

```
sudo chown user .config/octave
sudo chown user .config/octave/qt-settings
```

and then Octave opened OK.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that somehow the program doesn't see that who is the owner of the program. For that you need to do the following (that was mentioned by everyone) :

> cd .config/octave
>
> sudo chmod qt.settings

After this, open terminal and type: Octave. The program will run

My system: ubuntu 17.04 upgraded to gnome3

Answer (score -2):

```
cd .config/octave/
sudo chmod u+w qt-settings

cd .config/octave
sudo chown user qt-settings
```

*works for me even 16.04