# Octave GUI doesn't launch on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gui, octave

I have installed Octave using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:octave/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install octave
```

Typing octave --no-gui in the shell launches Octave command line. However, if I try opening octave GUI by typing octave or octave --force-gui, octave icon appears in the sidebar, and nothing else happens (no error message, either) and octave doesn't launch. Clicking on the icon doesn't do anything either.

I have tried following the accepted answer to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/292721/error-running-octave-in-ubuntu-16-04/293404?newreg=e3e46f098ad34444bc52e782e11ebad8) similar question, but when I write

> cd .config/octave

I get the following message:

> bash: cd: .config/octave: No such file or directory

Thanks.

Comment: What directory are you running the `cd` command from? Try `cd ~/.config/octave/`. I assume you're referring to the issue whereby the `qt-settings` directory becomes root-owned?

Comment: Thanks, now it works, but it didn't solve the issue. Could you please clarify your question regarding qt-settings? I am new to Linux.

Comment: I assume you already ran the `chown` command indicated in the linked answer?

Comment: Yes, it didn't solve the issue.